# Showing html formatting in wordpress post excerpt?

Tags: html, wordpress, formatting, shortcode

I'm using a custom theme for my wordpress site.

This code in post.class.php controls how the post excerpt looks:

```
    function get_excerpt($post, $ln){
        if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
            if (strlen(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_excerpt))) > $ln) {
                echo mb_substr(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_excerpt)), 0, $ln) . '[...]';
            } else {
                echo strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_excerpt));
            }
        } else {
            if (strlen(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content))) > $ln) {
                echo mb_substr(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content)), 0, $ln) . '[...]';
            } else {
                echo strip_tags(strip_shortcodes($post->post_content));
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I edit the above code so that the short code and html formatting is not stripped?

This is the code that configures how many characters are shown in the post excerpt (same file):

```
            <div class="excerpt">
                <?php
                    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                        $ln = 800; /*show first 800 characters*/
                        post::get_excerpt($post, $ln = $ln);
                    } else {
                        if ( !tools::is_nsfw( $post -> ID ) ) {
                            the_excerpt();
                        }else{
                            echo '<p>' . options::get_value( 'general' , 'nsfw_content' ) . '</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

UPDATE:  This is what code I ended up using to show html formatting:

```
 function get_excerpt($post, $ln){
        if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
            if (strlen($post->post_excerpt) > $ln) {
                echo mb_substr(($post->post_excerpt), 0, $ln);
            } 
        } else {
            if (strlen($post->post_content) > $ln) {
                  echo mb_substr(($post->post_content), 0, $ln);
            } 
        }

    }
```

I took out the strip_tags and strip_shortcodes and made the code more simplified.  I still have to figure out how to format the cut-off point for the mb_substr string but I'll make that a separate question.

Update: Here's the question I posted -> [mb_substr cutting off words in post excerpt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712543/mb-substr-cutting-off-words-in-post-excerpt)

Comment: Use `echo mb_substr($post->post_excerpt, 0, $ln)`.

Comment: I replaced the original instances of `mb_substr` with your code and now the post excerpts show [...] with no words.