# mb_substr cutting off words in post excerpt?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post, format

This is the code I am using to show html formatting on my wordpress post excerpts:

```
 function get_excerpt($post, $ln){
        if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
            if (strlen($post->post_excerpt) > $ln) {
                echo mb_substr(($post->post_excerpt), 0, $ln);
            } 
        } else {
            if (strlen($post->post_content) > $ln) {
                  echo mb_substr(($post->post_content), 0, $ln);
            } 
        }

    }
```

How can I edit the `mb_substr` so that the excerpt will end at a period?  For instance, an excerpt will end like this "she has a lovable and innocent charm tha" instead of "she has a lovable and innocent charm that keeps people caring about her."  I want the excerpt to finish the sentence and end in a period instead of only stopping at the character limit, which is set at 800.  In the code $ln is set to 800.

UPDATE:

This is the code I ended up using.  Words are still cut off in the excerpt but I added a Read More link to the end with dots.

```
 function get_excerpt($post, $ln){
    if (!empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
        if (strlen($post->post_excerpt) > $ln) {
            echo mb_substr(($post->post_excerpt), 0, $ln) . '...'; ?> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post -> ID )?>">[Read More]</a>
 <?php } 
    } else {
        if (strlen($post->post_content) > $ln) {
              echo mb_substr(($post->post_content), 0, $ln) . '...';?> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post -> ID )?>">[Read More]</a>
 <?php } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that there will be a "." in your text then you can just do this:

```
echo strtok("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sit amet egestas lacus. Maecenas posuere dolor vitae ultrices viverra.",".");
```

This will output: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"

[strtok manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php)

Comment: Each excerpt says different things so I never know when there will be a period but every excerpt has multiple sentences.  There is a period at different character limits.  I wish I could manipulate the mb_substr to put a "... [Read More]" at the end of the excerpt and then the Read More will have the excerpt's permalink.  Cutting off the excerpt at mid word looks bad.

Comment: But you guarantee that all excerpts will have at least one "."?

Technically, not answering the original question since I just checked and you did specify that you wanted to still use mb_substr but this would work:

`$excerpt = strtok($post->post_excerpt, ".");`
`$excerpt .= '...<a href="'.the_permalink().'">[Read More]</a>';`

Comment: But you guarantee that all excerpts will have at least one "."?

Yes, there is at least one "." in every excerpt.  So how do I make mb_substr end at a specific "."  For instance, if every excerpt has 5 periods, how can I end the excerpts at the second period?